# Retrieving a specific row depending on a date variable?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have 7 columns that which contain the information of closing times, each for one day. (It goes like VENUE_CLOSE_T_MO, VENUE_CLOSE_T_TU... etc)

How would I, for example choose one of those columns depending on a date variable ($somevariable) which contains a specific date?

For example, if the date variable was Sunday, March 18 22:00, it would choose column VENUE_CLOSE_T_SU.

Thanks for the help everyone!

**EDIT (Solution given by TEEZ that solved the issue)**

My Date variable is **$Start**.

And this is the code:

```
$day_name=strtoupper(date('D',$start));
$day_name=substr($day_name,0,2);
$selectcolumn='VENUE_CLOSE_T_'.$day_name;
```

So in this case **$selectcolumn** = VENUE_CLOSE_T_SU

And the echo is then this:

```
$row[$selectcolumn]
```

Thanks for all your help again Teez!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first get day name from variable `($somevariable)`

```
$day_name=strtoupper(date('D',$somevariable));
```

then make query like below for getting column according to day in $somevariable

```
select concat('VENUE_CLOSE_T_',left($day_name,2)) as datecolumnname  from tableame
```

**EDIT:**

OR

you don't need to do this in query if you taking all column in query. just add these lines in php code where you printing data in we page under date column

```
$day_name=strtoupper(date('D',$somevariable));
$day_name=substr($day_name,0,2);
$selectcolumn='venues.VENUE_CLOSE_T_'.$day_name; 
echo $row[$selectcolumn];
```

Comment: Hey Teez, thanks for your answer! So what your code even does is that it takes the name of the day and shortens is to two letters, so that I can keep the name of my columns as such (MO, TU, WE, TH, FR etc)?

Comment: Hmm, I get this error: `Unknown column 'SUN' in 'field list'`. I will post my code above.

Comment: Add column alias :


    select concat('venues.VENUE_CLOSE_T_',left($day_name,2)) as datecolumnname  from tableame

Comment: No Luck. I think that the code just writes 'SUN' as in Sunday instead of combining it, at least I think.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9023/discussion-between-pufamuf-and-teez)

Comment: Solved, Thank you so much. Teez dedicated a lot of his time to help me. I really appreciate it!